# Search panel missing on jira issues page on chrome

Tags: jira

The screenshot below is from Jira in Chrome and another from Jira in Edge.  Why is the search panel missing from chrome?  I'm running Chrome v102.0.5005.115.  I deleted all cache & cookies in chrome for the jira site I use, but I still don't get the search panel.

## **Jira in Chrome**

[image: Jira in Chrome]

## **Jira in Edge**

[image: Jira in Edge]

Comment: You might want to take a look at browser's console (`F12`) and check if there are any related errors. The root cause might be related to any Jira customization or Chrome extension (also try Incognito window in Chrome to check the behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Try running your JIRA in safe mode to find out the root cause of this problem (see [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/upm/disabling-and-enabling-apps-273875716.html) for details).

If this resolves your problem, you must find out the plugins you installed and disable them one after the other from the latest. You can see in the log files if there are any server side errors (see [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/useful-log-files-in-jira-1027120387.html) for details).